# Find the numbers in string and Sum them using list comprehension [sum only 1-9]

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, sum

```
>>> a = "L2-L3"
>>> removeword = ["L","-"]
>>> add = [sum(int(j) for j in i) for i in a.strip() if i not in removeword]
>>> print(add)
[2, 3] # expected 5
```

I want to do the sum in list comprehension

Thanks

Comment: What would you want if you had `"L12-L3"` ?

Comment: change to `add = sum([int(j) for j in i for i in a.strip() if i not in removeword])`

Comment: *"I want to do the sum in list comprehension"* No, you really don't. You want to do it outside of the comprehension, otherwise you'll end up with a list of sums.

Comment: output is 4 need 5

Comment: done like this sum(int(j) for j in add) working but any way to do it in  list comprehension

Comment: i wat it to sum number only 1-9